# X buys sweets at $11$ for rupee $\large\bf{(₹)}$. Bought equal number of sweets at $10$ for rupee. Sold all sweets at $8$ for rupee. Find loss/gain.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, percentages, word-problem

A Shopkeeper buys sweets at $11$ for a rupee $\large\bf{(₹)}$. He bought an equal number of sweets at $10$ for a rupee. He sold all the sweets at $8$ for a rupee. Find loss or gain percentage.

Please solve this for me. I am not able to understand this statement. Can you also explain the meaning of this problem statement ?

Comment: Pick a convenient number for the number of sweets (say, $110$) and figure out how much he paid and how much he took in.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  For this problem, $1$ is probably a whole lot more convenient than $110$.

Comment: @WillO, not if you prefer whole numbers to fractions. In fact, 220 of each type of sweet might be even better than 110.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Ah.  I read it as "sweets at 11 rupees", whereas it's "sweets at 11 for a rupee".  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was totally **wrong** and I apologize. Let me start again.

Per unit, the shopkeeper pays $\frac{1}{11}$ for the first kind of sweets and $\frac{1}{10}$ for the second kind of sweets. This makes an average value of $\frac{21}{220}$ when he buys. When he sells the sweets, he charges $\frac{1}{8}$ per unit. The difference is then $\frac{1}{8}-\frac{21}{220}=\frac{13}{440}$ and this is the profit per unit. Then, dividing the profit per unit by the price paid per unit, this gives $\frac{13}{42}$ which is almost $31$ percents.

Comment: 11 sweets and 10 sweets are "an equal number of sweets" ?

Comment: @WillO. I do not see what you mean. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The problem statement says that the shopkeeper buys some number of sweets at 11 and *an equal number* of sweets at 10.  Your solution assumes he buys 11 sweets at 1/11 and 10 sweets at 1/10.  11 and 10 are not equal numbers.  Also, $1/11\neq 11$ and $1/10\neq 10$.

Comment: The fractions are the prices

Comment: But, Claude, he bought the same number of sweets at the two prices; you've got him paying the same amount for the two types. If he bought 11 of the first type, then he also bought 11 of the second type, not 10.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. I am a terrible business man, I know ! So, I still do not see what is wrong in my reasoning. Please explain the old man ! Cheers.

Comment: I am totaly stupid. Sorry about it ! I rewrite my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asks for a percentage we may as well assume that he bought one sweet of each kind for a total of ${1\over11}+{1\over10}={21\over110}$ rupees and sold the two sweets for $2\cdot{1\over8}={1\over4}$ rupees. His  gain therefore was ${1\over4}-{21\over110}={13\over220}$ rupees, and these make up the fraction
$${13/220\over 21/110}={13\over 42}\doteq 31\%$$
of his initial investment.

Answer (score -1):

He bought each sweet for 100 paisa/10 = 10 paisa;
he sold each sweet for 100 paisa/8 = 12.5 paisa.

So the gain% = ( (buying price - selling price) * 100 ) / selling price.